# Listening for incoming messages from TCP server causes StackOverflow

Tags: java, tcp, bufferedreader, stack-overflow, message-loop

I need to continuously listen for messages from my C# TCP server, so I do it in separate thread:

```
private void StartMessageReceivingLoop()
{       
    new Thread(){
        public void run()
        {
            String msg = null;

            try
            {
                msg = inputStream.readLine(); // inputStream is a BufferedReader instance.
            } 
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (msg != null && msg != "")
                NotifyAndForwardMessage(msg); // Notify listeners about the message.

            run(); // Next iteration.
        }
    }.start();
}
```

What's wrong with my approach? Why am I getting a StackOverflowError? I'm guessing that `run()` is invoked incredibly fast because `BufferedReader.readLine()` is non-blocking, but what can I do about it?

Comment: Why are you doing this recursively?

Comment: Well I could put `run()` contents in a `while` loop but there's really no difference, is there?

Comment: Yeah, seems so. I'm an idiot.

Comment: The difference is that the loop doesn't get a stack overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't call `run()` within `run()`. This is not a recursive function. If you want to keep reading until some condition, wrap this in a while loop. By calling the method you are executing while you are executing it, you are creating another stack frame. What you really want is just to loop.

```
public void run() {
   String msg = null;
   while(true) {  // Or whatever your exit condition is...
      try {
         msg = inputStream.readLine();
      } catch(IOException e) {
         // Handle properly.
      }
      if (msg != null && msg != "") {
          NotifyAndForwardMessage(msg);
      }
   }
}
```

To help illustrate, it kind of works like this...

```
Thread.start()
   + run() // 1 (called by thread)
      + run() // 2 (called by previous run)
         + run() //3 (called by previous run)
            +etc... where you'll eventually run out of stack space.
```

Comment: Another rookie mistake. Thanks for your explanation.